# Remove E sign from big float number , C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point, numbers

If you used big float numbers , you found in C# big float number is showed like this : 
2000000 * 2000000 = 4E+12

How can I show **4E+12** as 4,000,000,000,000 not **4E+12** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want

```
number.ToString("N0");
```

"N0" is Number with no decimal places.

The alternative - "F0" is Fixed-point with no decimal places but prints without the comma separators:

```
double number = 4e12;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("F0"));
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("N0"));
```

prints:

```
4000000000000
4,000,000,000,000
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: @Gunner Even with float the result will be "accurately represented" (as accurately represented as it is in the float itself, anyway). A double should be good for all integers up to that range, and a decimal can go a good bit further.

Answer (score 0):

Really great answer!

My code is

```
Double dblAcct = (Double)childRow["Account No"];
s_acct = dblAcct.ToString("F0");
s_acct = s_acct.PadLeft(16, '0');
```